# convergence in distribution and uniform integrability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I want to show that if $X_{n}\to X$ in distribution and $X_{n}$'s are uniformly integrable then
$E[|X|]<\infty$ and $E[X_{n}]\to E[X]$.

Now for the first part I argue like this.

Since the $X_{n}$'s are uniformly integrable then $E[|X_{n}|]<M$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Where $M$ is some fixed real number. ( I have already proved that such a an M exist and is finite.)

Now by Fatou's Lemma . $E[|X|]\leq\lim\inf\,E[|X_{n}|]\leq M<\infty$.

Next I want to show that $E[X_{n}]\to E[X]$.

If I try and use Skorokhod's representation theorem(Which was only stated as a theorem in class. This is an elementary probability course). Then I can use $Y_{n}\to Y$ almost surely and $Y_{n}$ has same distributions as $X_{n}$ and $Y$ has same distribution as $X$. Now I want to use the dominated convergence theorem but I do not know what rv should I use to dominate $Y_{n}$'s .

Any help is appreciated. I do not have a background in measure theory . So please try and answer in terms of probability.

Comment: You  cannot use DCT. There is no reason why the sequence is dominated by an integral r.v.

Comment: You can use that $(Y_n)$ is uniformly integrable. (Since $Y_n\to Y$ a.s. it holds also in measure, so you have that $Y_n\to Y$ in $L^1$. In particular $E[X_n]=E[Y_n]\to E[Y]=E[X]$.)

Comment: @nejimban . I can prove that if $Y_{n}\to Y$ in probability and they are uniformly integrable then $E[|Y_{n}-Y|]\to 0$. Would that suffice?

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Yes! $|E[Y_n]-E[Y]|\le E[|Y_n-Y|]$.

Comment: You can prove this wihtout Skhorohod representation. Are you interested in such a proof?

Comment: Okay thanks. The proof I had written down for that ( it was the previous question in my practice problem sheet) was a little long. So I thought if I could use a shorter method . Btw is there a shorter proof than that?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes please. I am very much interested in various ways of proving this. Especially since I do not even understand the proof of skorokhod entirely. This is way to heavy for a first probability course( well the first time I am doing a probability course).

Comment: Also @KaviRamaMurthy is my proof using fatou's lemma for the first part correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct but you should change $<$ to $\leq $.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy ah yes thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof without appealing to Skorokhod's representation theorem:

Let $K\ge0$. The map $h_K:x\mapsto\min(K,\max(-K,x))$ is continuous and bounded (by $K$). The convergence in distribution $X_n\to X$ then implies
$$\mathbb E[h_K(X_n)]\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\mathbb E[h_k(X)].$$
Further, it is easy to check that
$|x-h_K(x)|\le |x|\mathbf 1_{\{|x|>K\}}$ for any $x\in\mathbb R$, so by
triangular inequality
\begin{align*}
\bigl|\mathbb E[X_n-X]\bigr|&\le\mathbb E\bigl[\lvert X_n-h_K(X_n)\rvert\bigr]+\bigl\lvert
\mathbb E[h_K(X_n)-h_K(X)]\bigr\rvert+\mathbb E\bigl[\lvert h_K(X)-X\rvert\bigr]\\[.4em]
&\le\mathbb E\bigl[\lvert X_n\rvert\mathbf 1_{\{\lvert X_n\rvert>K\}}\bigr]+o(1)+\mathbb E\bigl[\lvert X\rvert\mathbf 1_{\{\lvert X\rvert>K\}}\bigr].
\end{align*}
This together with the uniform integrability of $(X_n)_{n\ge1}$ shows that
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\:\bigl|\mathbb E[X_n-X]\bigr|\le\mathbb E\bigl[\lvert X\rvert\mathbf 1_{\{\lvert X\rvert>K\}}\bigr].$$
Now, letting $K\to\infty$, because $X$ is integrable (as you showed with Fatou's lemma), you can conclude by the dominated convergence theorem (or the monotone convergence theorem) that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb E[X_n]=\mathbb E[X].$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!